# Erro ao executar código em Python.Estou fazendo algo de errado ou é um problema no meu IDLE?

Tags: python

Sou iniciante em Python e logo quando fui testar o módulo Turtle pela primeira vez ele rodou normalmente quando eu fui digitando os comandos e executando a cada linha. Entretanto, quando salvei os mesmos comandos em um arquivo próprio e o executei, aparecia uma mensagem de erro dizendo que os comandos não estavam sendo reconhecidos,mesmo eu tendo importado a biblioteca e ela tendo funcionado no método anterior. Exemplo:

```
from turtle import *
fd(100)
bye()
```

E então aparece a mensagem "NameError: name 'fd' is not defined", sendo que eu já tentei diferentes maneiras de escrever esse mesmo código e sempre tem um erro semelhante. Isso é uma característica do IDLE ou eu estou fazendo algo de errado?

Comment: Eu sei que é uma pergunta bem boba mas surpreendentemente isso ocorre muitas vezes... você já viu se o seu programa está sendo executado num mesmo diretório que tenha um arquivo .py chamado "turtle" ? Se sim, o erro está sendo causado porque você está importando o módulo turtle deste diretório e não da biblioteca do Python.

Comment: Quando você faz print(turtle) antes de chamar a função fd(100) é retornando o que exatamente?

Comment: JeanExtreme002 - Sim...o nome do arquivo era "turtle",também,mas agora mudei e está funcionando normalmente,que erro bobo...não teria descoberto sozinho,muito obrigado e me desculpe pela demora a responder.

Comment: Bart - Mostra "NameError: name 'turtle' is not defined",mas seja como for,agora já está funcionando,obrigado pela atenção.